# scatter plot of binary and continuous variable

Tags: variables, stata, binary-data, continuous, type-conversion

I want to see the scatter plot of barrier score (binary variable) and age (a continuous variable). I want to convert my barrier score to continuous.

1. I used the command `collapse (mean) barrierscore, by (Age)`
2. I renamed `barrierscore` by `rename barrierscore prbarrierscore`
3. Next I use the command `generate logit barrierscore1=ln(prbarrierscore/(1-prbarrierscore))`

The problem is that I am receiving the error message:

> too many variables specified
>
> r(103);

Am I making a mistake with the commands?

Comment: You have an issue with the syntax for `generate`. It only takes one name for the new variable,  and you are feeding it two: `logit` and `barrierscore1`.  Therefore,  it complains.

Comment: You can't combine `generate` and `logit` in one statement.  It's either one command or the other. Stata complains that you are trying to give two names to the new variable. One `logit`, the other `barrierscore1`.

Comment: The recommendation is to read [[U] User's Guide](http://www.stata.com/bookstore/users-guide), which includes instructions on how to read a command's _syntax diagram_, like the one found in `help generate`.

Comment: Thank You So much Roberto Ferrer, for your kind advice. I was doing the same mistake. I am done with that

Be blessed

Comment: Note that Stata has an inbuilt `logit()` function.